# Arduino Uno + 12 relays

Tags: arduino-uno, relay

I'm using a basic relay and I want to use 12 like this. Each one needs 50 milliamps, but the Arduino can supply only 300 milliamps. What can I do?

Comment: Use transistors.

Answer (score 2):

You should never drive relays direct from an Arduino.  You always need a driver circuit since each OP pin can only reliably provide up to 25mA.

Every relay needs (at least) an NPN transistor and a flyback diode.  Follow the myriad of examples for controlling one relay on an Arduino and multiply it by 12.

You might like to make things smaller and more manageable by using a paur of ULN2303 chips with 6 darlington drivers in each instead of using 12 discrete transistors.

Comment: Im using a transistor for each one. But it still take 50 milli amper. Can you show me a circuit?

Comment: @MyNick If you are managing to draw 50mA into the base of a transistor then they must be massive transistors driving house sized relays.   If you are talking about the power supply current draw not the IO pin current draw, then just get a bigger power supply.

Comment: Regular transistors that comes from the kit.

Comment: @MyNick Then I have to assume (rightly or wrongly, I can't tell since you won't tell me) that you're referring to the power supply current not the IO pin current, in which case - what is your problem? Just use a more powerful power supply for the relays. If you are actually referring to the IO current then god help your Arduino.

Comment: This is the circuit for each relay, it takes 50 milli amper from the io pin: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=7c60d62fee&view=fimg&th=150943794c75955d&attid=0.1&disp=inline&realattid=1515816904198979584-local0&safe=1&attbid=ANGjdJ9eRNUCnxNPSMue9eI_2SEzxRP7jg00s0ty_jgJJyrD0-eI94xWwlpXSn3q5KYgrIP9QpdxBgSG9mscZxEcG1LzmsNXXF_pkVixDsEDKtTO0iYZkN9fHF6MzoE&ats=1445596069379&rm=150943794c75955d&zw&sz=w1256-h819

Comment: @MyNick You know, much as I would love to be able to read your email, I just can't afford the time trying to hack it.

Comment: tried to give the link to the image. nvm here you go: http://puu.sh/kUxyk/4a53ce59e5.jpg

Comment: I see only 4.3mA, not 50mA.

Comment: I just a circuit that a friend drew for me. He told me that the current is not real and i should try to build it and check it. (he just put random values or something). I built it and it took 50 ma (i checked it using multi meter)

Comment: ***WHERE*** did it take 50mA? At what point in the circuit?

Comment: between the io and the resistor into the base of the transistor.

Comment: In that case there is something very wrong with your circuit. Given a typical Hfe of 100 you would then expect the transistor to be passing around 5A.  It would literally be on fire.

Comment: i found that circuit example : https://www.flickr.com/photos/anachrocomputer/3242387876/in/pool-make
how does the resistor makes a different? if i use 300 ohm what will happen?

Comment: @MyNick Yes, that is the normal basic relay driving circuit.

Comment: and if i use 300ohm resistor and not 1k?

Comment: Then you raise the current allowed through the base, and thus the maximum through the colletcor.  300Ω should be fine, but 1K is better since it limits the maximum that can be drawn from the IO pin.

Comment: Ok now i get it, Thank you so much for all of your time